# Could not determine executable to run when building apk react native expo

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, expo

I'm attempting to create an APK for my app using the command "npx eas build -p android --profile preview," but I've encountered an issue with the message "could not determine executable to run."

Error below
npm ERR! could not determine executable to run

So, I've already attempted to clear the Node.js modules cache and reinstall Node.js. Also I've changed eas.json file

```
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 0.52.0"
  },
  "build": {
    "preview": {
      "android": {
        "buildType": "apk"
      }
    },
    "preview2": {
      "android": {
        "gradleCommand": ":app:assembleRelease"
      }
    },
    "preview3": {
      "developmentClient": true
    },
    "production": {}
  }
}
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)